# A java Card game program problem with the dealHands, dealCard and displayHands methods

Tags: java

So I have a homework at school I`m struggling right now.

Since I`m pretty new to programming, some logic might seem a little bit confusing.

I`m trying to follow the instructions the teacher gave, but wonder if this program will ever compile if do it his way.

When I try to compile, the system always gives me an error in the dealHands method.
I`m also struggling with the displayHands method, if anyone could help give some suggestions.

The desirable outcome would look like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihDAT.jpg)

A few things I don`t really get are:

1. If we could use a toString method to convert int to card String, I believe would be more easier, I don`t know if my convertCard method is going to work or not...

2.The dealHands method, is the way I call the method dealCard the right way? and is the way I assign the int j the right way?

3. Does the deal Card method needs a loop? Can the dealCard method I wrote work?
4. Is there a good way to design displayHands method using a double for loop? how can I get it to display the result the teacher desired?

Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardGame {


//class level variables you may use to convert numbers from 0-51 to a card.
public static final String[] cardNumbers = 
{"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"};
public static final String[] cardSuits = {"D","H","C","S"};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Your deck of cards.
    //True means the card is still in the deck, false means it has been dealt
    boolean[] deck = new boolean[52];  

    //A 2D array that holds Strings.
    //The first perameter will determine the number of players.
    //The second perameter will determine how many cards they will hold.  It should always be 5.
    String[][] players;

    //boolean variable used to determine if the user would like to play again.
    boolean playAgain;

    do{

        players = playerPrompt(scr);        //create and store the 2D array
        resetDeck(deck);                    //reset the deck so all cards are present
        dealHands(players, deck);           //deal out cards to each player
        displayHands(players);              //show each players hands
        playAgain = playerRePrompt(scr);    //see if the player wishes to play again


    } while (playAgain);

    System.out.println("Thank you, goodbye");
    scr.close();
}


/**
 * Ask the user how many players they want to play.
 * Make sure the number entered is between 2 and 8.
 * A player can only hold 5 cards at a time.
 * Return a new 2D String containing the total players and the amount of cards they can hold.
 * ie. new String[totalPlayers][5];
 * 
 * @param Scanner scr
 * @return String[][]
 */
public static String[][] playerPrompt (Scanner scr){

        int totalPlayers = 0;                              // TODO    
        System.out.print("How many people are playing?");   
        String thePlayers = scr.nextLine();
        totalPlayers = Integer.parseInt(thePlayers);

            while ((totalPlayers<2)||(totalPlayers>8))  
                    {
        System.out.print("Please re-enter a number between 2 adn 8. How many people are playing?");
            thePlayers = scr.nextLine();
        totalPlayers = Integer.parseInt(thePlayers);
      }  

        String[][] players = new String[totalPlayers][5];
        return players;
}


/**
 * Ask the player if they want to play again.
 * Return true if they want to play again, false otherwise.
 * The only way to quit is by entering "no".
 * 
 * @param Scanner scr
 * @return boolean
 */

public static boolean playerRePrompt (Scanner scr){

    boolean playAgain;    // TODO
    do{
    System.out.print("Would you like to deal again?(Type \"no\" to quit.)");//TODO
    String answer = scr.nextLine();

    if (answer.equals("no"))
    {

        playAgain=false;
        System.out.println("Thank you, goodbye");
        break;
    }  
    else if (answer.equals("yes"))
    {
        playAgain=true;
        System.out.println("Thank you, goodbye");
        break;
    }   

  } while (playAgain = true);
  return playAgain;
}


/**
 * Reset the deck for the next round.
 * Think of this as collecting all the cards.
 * A card is in the deck if it's value is true.
 * 
 * @param boolean [] deck
 */
public static void resetDeck(boolean[] deck){

    deck = new boolean[52]; //TODO

}


/**
 * Deal out the cards to each player.
 * The 2D String array called players will hold the card values.
 * See the assignment description for a visual of how this will work.
 * You will need to call dealCard and use a double for loop to fill the 2D String array.
 * 
 * @param players
 * @param deck
 */
public static void dealHands(String[][] players, boolean[] deck){


    int i = players.length;               //TODO
    String set = CardGame.dealCard(deck);
    int j = Integer.parseInt(set);
    players = new String[i][j];
    for (i=0; i<players.length;i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            players = new String[i][j];
        }
    }

}


/**
 * Deal one card from the deck.
 * Use the boolean array to tell if a card has been dealt yet.
 * You will need to call convertCard to convert the index of an available card to it's correct card representation.
 * You will need to use a random number generator to simulate an actual shuffled deck.
 * Remember, Math.random() returns a number from 0 to .99999....
 * 
 * @param deck
 * @return String
 */
public static String dealCard(boolean[] deck){

            //TODO
    int card = deck.length - 51;
    int rand = (int)(Math.random() * card + 1);
    String handCard = CardGame.convertCard(rand);
    return handCard;
}


/**
 * Given a number between 0 and 51, convert that number to the correct format.
 * It is up to you how each card is converted, just make sure that each number is mapped to a unique card.
 * Just make sure a mapping is 1 to 1, meaning if 4 converts to "4C", it will always convert to "4C"
 * Also make sure it is possible for each card to be dealt.
 * 
 * I have provided two arrays at the top, cardNumbers and cardSuits you may use if you wish.
 * There is clever way to convert a number using modulus and division, and this method can be done in one line.
 * 
 * @param card
 * @return String representing a card in correct format
 */
public static String convertCard(int card){

              String numbers = cardNumbers[card%13];      //TODO
              String suits = cardSuits[card/13];

              return numbers + suits;
        }



/**
 * Display all the players hands to the console.
 * You will need a double for loop.
 * 
 * @param players
 */
public static void displayHands(String[][] players){

    for(int i = 0; i<players.length; i++)//TODO
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<5; j++)
                {
                System.out.println("Player" + i + "hand: " + j);    


     }


    }
```

}
}

Comment: What is the specific error you're seeing?

Comment: run:
How many people are playing?6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3D"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at CardGame.dealHands(CardGame.java:134)
 at CardGame.main(CardGame.java:30)
C:\Users\borne\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

Comment: This is the message it gives me when I try to run the program, happens at the dealHands method

Answer (score 0):

I will show you your error:

In the method `dealHands` you are calling

```
String set = CardGame.dealCard(deck);
int j = Integer.parseInt(set);
```

`CardGame.dealCard` do:

```
String handCard = CardGame.convertCard(rand);
```

`CardGame.convertCard` by its side does:

```
public static String convertCard(int card){

          String numbers = cardNumbers[card%13];      
          String suits = cardSuits[card/13];    // This array contains letters

          return numbers + suits; // Here is returned a number concatenated with a letter
}
```

returning to `CardGame.dealHands` method, you are trying to convert the result (e.g. "3D") to an integer value

```
String set = CardGame.dealCard(deck);
int j = Integer.parseInt(set); // set in this case is a number + a letter (e.g: "5C")
```

and that is where the execution fails.

if you debug that (and even the output in console said it), you will notice it:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: **For input string: "3D"** at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at **java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is there any better way to improve dealHands method?